# Starcraft2 minigame doesn't run

Tags: python, dll

I tried to run pysc2 random agent following this : https://github.com/deepmind/pysc2

I run the command in PyCharm terminal, no errors are displayed, but a **"Failed to load"** window appears:

> "Critical error during loading process.Required library 'icuuc52.dll'
>   does not exist"

when program was still running like this:

```
I0411 20:40:50.163242  4560 remote_controller.py:163] Connecting to: ws://127.0.0.1:22531/sc2api, attempt: 0, running
: True

I0411 20:40:52.189565  4560 remote_controller.py:163] Connecting to: ws://127.0.0.1:22531/sc2api, attempt: 1, running
: True

I0411 20:40:54.223120  4560 remote_controller.py:163] Connecting to: ws://127.0.0.1:22531/sc2api, attempt: 2, running
: True
```

I started game from Battle.net and everything is ok.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download from this site: https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/mozilla-foundation/firefox/icuuc52-dll/

Install and run StarCraft2. It will be works.

Comment: If you have knowledge about this problem, perhaps you could also direct OP to a reference about the issue eg. how/why it arises? Rather than simply inviting them to download a binary from a 3rd party website :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by backgrading the version of pycharm to 2018.3.6.

However, I still don't know the reason.